# SQL query - need help in forming sql query

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Please can some one advise me on below issue: I need solution for below SQL  query. The database is Oracle 11g.

```
Select 
    article_cd, dc_cd, 
    nvl(soh_to_dmp - least(soh_to_dmp, nvl(sum(adj_alc_tot_frcst), 0)) ,0) v_dump_qty,
    used_by_date 
from 
    inventory
```

I have attached a screenshot to show data in table format

[please refer to this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfXMn.png)

I want a column "shirink " which gives" dump qty - sum ( all previous shrink) and if dump qty - sum ( all the previous shrink) <0 then 0 as shown in above screenshot shrink for 777 = 0 for 0 = (0-777) = -777 and this should be 0 for 2548 = (2548 - 777 ) = 1771 for 8356 = ( 8356 -( 777+1771) ) = 5808

I tried using lag function :

```
v_dump qty- lag ( v_dump qty) over ( partition by article_code,dc_code) order by ( article_code, dc code, used_date)
```

but it did not work

Comment: Perhaps a Case When statement might help if your database engine supports that. What DB are you using?

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide a SQL query that is syntactically correct.

Comment: Regardless of the code, are you sure the math (the logic) is correct? The formula you are trying to implement doesn't make a lot of sense to me (from a logical perspective - nothing to do with programming at all).

Comment: My question was how to  form a formula  for column shirnk where it looks for previous shink and subtracts from the shirnk and going forward it considers this calculated shrink  for next shrink ?  Iam now sure why it is logically incorrect

Answer (score 0):

The following queries may provide a starting point for solving your problem.  We do not have a lot of test data right now.  However, when we use an "inventory" table, filled with test data, looking like this:

```
create table inventory(
  iid number primary key
, usebydate date
, qty number
);
-- select * from inventory
IID USEBYDATE   QTY
1   30-AUG-2017 0
2   31-AUG-2017 0
3   30-SEP-2017 777
4   30-OCT-2017 0
5   01-NOV-2017 0
6   16-NOV-2017 0
7   30-NOV-2017 0
8   01-JAN-2018 0
9   31-JAN-2018 2548
10  28-FEB-2018 8356
```

... it can be seen that a query that contains a self-join, combined with CASE, and "windowing", may provide the result that you need.

```
select 
  i.iid
, i.qty 
, case 
    when ( i.qty - ( sum(i2.shrink) over ( order by i.iid rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) ) ) < 0 
      or ( i.qty - ( sum(i2.shrink) over ( order by i.iid rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) ) ) is null
      then 0
    else ( i.qty - ( sum(i2.shrink) over ( order by i.iid rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) ) )
  end shrink 
from inventory i join 
  ( select 
      iid
    , case 
        when ( qty - ( sum(qty) 
          over ( order by iid rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding ) ) ) < 0 then 0
        else ( qty - ( sum(qty) 
              over ( order by iid rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) ) )
       end shrink
       from inventory
   ) i2
   on i.iid = i2.iid
order by i.iid
;
```

Output:

```
IID QTY     SHRINK
1   0       0
2   0       0
3   777     777
4   0       0
5   0       0
6   0       0
7   0       0
8   0       0
9   2548    1771
10  8356    5808
```

The same query, with the "usebydate" in the ON clause, gives us:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  on clause with date instead of iid
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
select 
  i.usebydate
, i.qty 
, case 
    when ( i.qty - ( sum(i2.shrink) over ( order by i.usebydate rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) ) ) < 0 
      or ( i.qty - ( sum(i2.shrink) over ( order by i.usebydate rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) ) ) is null
      then 0
    else ( i.qty - ( sum(i2.shrink) over ( order by i.usebydate rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) ) )
  end shrink 
from inventory i join 
  ( select 
      usebydate
    , case 
        when ( qty - ( sum(qty) 
          over ( order by usebydate rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding ) ) ) < 0 then 0
        else ( qty - ( sum(qty) 
              over ( order by usebydate rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) ) )
       end shrink
       from inventory
   ) i2
   on i.usebydate = i2.usebydate
order by i.usebydate
;

-- output
    USEBYDATE   QTY     SHRINK
    30-AUG-2017 0       0
    31-AUG-2017 0       0
    30-SEP-2017 777     777
    30-OCT-2017 0       0
    01-NOV-2017 0       0
    16-NOV-2017 0       0
    30-NOV-2017 0       0
    01-JAN-2018 0       0
    31-JAN-2018 2548    1771
    28-FEB-2018 8356    5808
```

I'm sure this can be modified/simplified.  Also, it will need thorough testing.  Works with: Oracle 12c, Oracle 11g R2.  dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7046b537591daec1fa879287df05fae1)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply , Thanks a lot for your help .  It was resolved  next day , my colleague helped me with the query .  Some how I missed your answer , I did not get any update from this forum .Thanks a lot for your help . I learnt lot from this answer

Comment: @user361245 Thanks for your feedback!  Much appreciated.